# uTorrent free internet?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, p2p

I run a windows operating system and I've installed the uTorrent app on my pc. I am from India. India has a ISP provider namely 'Reliance Jio'. I am a resident of a government hostel which has a Wi-Fi connection of JioNet. This Wi-Fi gives us a daily 34MB data for normal web surfing when we students sign in this JioNet Wi-Fi using our phone numbers. To sign in we follow a few simple steps

1. connect to Wi-Fi
2. after that the browser opens up and automatically shows up the signup portal....we have just entered our phone numbers ….and then we get a verification code    …and then we get the internet access with a data limit of 34MB for the whole day.

**Now lets move to the miracle that I discovered!**

one day I connected to the Wi-Fi and I skipped the signup process (i was not connected to the internet. I was just connected to the Wi-Fi).

I opened up my uTorrent app and resumed my torrent download. To my surprise, within a few minutes i saw the download has been already initiated with a speed of 2MB/sec and that too without signing in to the internet through the hostel Wi-Fi. I was just connected to the Wi-Fi. in the browser it showed that i am still disconnected to the internet. but in uTorrent I was having a file downloading at a very good speed and that too completed in a few minutes. I downloaded 2.3GB that day in a few minutes without connecting to the internet through the Wi-Fi. still the pc showed no internet access symbol....but at the same time I was downloading large files on uTorrent. I have downloaded a torrent file as large as 13GB absolutely free of cost using this uTorrent miraculous app!

I am eager to know how the uTorrent app did that miracle. it works wonders! unbelievable!

please tell me exactly how this miracle happened. What steps did uTorrent followed to do this cool thing. Please, I am eager for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you browse the internet while connected to WIFI and not logged in? If it is showing no internet access, maybe it just means you can't access the internet through HTTP/HTTPs, HTTP uses TCP port 80, HTTPs uses TCP port 443, and if these ports are banned while you aren't logged in you can't browse the internet, but the fact you can download files through uTorrent suggests that the other ports are open and not banned, standard BitTorrent protocol uses ports 6881 through 6889, however in reality BitTorrent clients may use any port available(maximum possible TCP port number is 65535), maybe these ports are not banned and can allow communication.

A possible way to verify this theory is to try to ping an external public IP address while connected to WIFI and not internet, I don't know about India but here behind the GFW I can still ping 8.8.8.8 even with VPN off, so I think ping 8.8.8.8 is good. If the result isn't timeout, it means you have network connectivity, but unable to browse the webpages if it shows No Internet Access, maybe the message actually means "can't connect to the internet through port 80,443(and possibly 20, 21 for FTP)", means no HTTP(s) and FTP access but it doesn't indicate the other protocols aren't working.

Note Ping requests utilize ICMP and don't use TCP ports.

---

Okay, a TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) port number is a 16 bit unsigned integer (0 - 65535 or 2^16-1) as a label in the header of an IP (Internet Protocol) packet, that's used together with with the IP address (32 bit unsigned integer for IPv4 or 128 bit unsigned integer for IPv6) to denote where the packet should be send to, like 151.101.1.69:80, the first is one of the IPv4 addresses of superuser.com, the second is the port number. IP address says which machine should receive the packet, and port number says which application.

When you type website addresses to address bar, for example superuser.com, the webpage address is automatically resolved to IP addresses by DNS servers so that computers can know where to send.

I don't know about the older days of internet but today in 2020s web browsers autocompletes webpage addresses and protocols, for example typing google.com in the address bar it automatically resolves to https://www.google.com, and it is the same as https://www.google.com:443, the port number is automatically added based on protocol, 443 for HTTPS(HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure), port 80 for HTTP and 20 for FTP (File Transfer Protocol).

Nowadays web browsers automatically use HTTPS connections, typing google.com and hitting Enter will automatically lead you to https://www.google.com:443, even if you specificy the protocol and port number: http://www.google.com:80, it will automatically redirect you to the HTTPS one(indicated by the locked lock symbol, clicking the address bar will show full address).

The web request is sent out as an outbound IP packet towards the server, the website address is automatically translated to IP address by DNS (Domain Name System) servers (or your hosts file if it finds a entry for the web address first), typically directly using IP address in the address bar wouldn't work, and then your packet goes through routers modems and firewalls, lots of firewalls, typically firewalls will inspect the receiver's IP address and prevent the packet from reaching its receiver if the receiver's IP is banned, among other things.

However in your case, the packet goes through the firewall of your local WIFI first, the firewall inspects the ports of the receiver, and if it's 20,80,443,6875 and possibly others while you aren't logged in, it simply ends the transmission of the packet, for you to access a website you need to send an outbound packet to the server and the server has to send back an inbound packet to you, now the outbound packet never reaches its destination and that's it, however not all ports are banned, as you have discovered, ports 6885, 48000 and 50000 aren't banned, so the firewall only intercepts ports in the blacklist and doesn't intercept ports not in blacklist.

Brilliant step on diagnosis, really, changing the port number uTorrent uses is the right step, and about ping timeout, there are two possibilities: 1, your country's firewall or any number of firewalls between you and Google had banned 8.8.8.8(not likely); 2, in addition to TCP/UDP ports, ICMP is also banned (most likely). To know which is the case, log in to your WIFI and ping 8.8.8.8 again, if still timeout then the first one is correct, if not then the second one.

---

And about how the firewall prevents your packet from reaching the destination, it is very simple; There is no central server of the internet, internet isn't provided by one big ISP, but rather peering of multiple ISPs and consists of God knows how many hops, nodes, routers and computers, smart phones and so on and so forth, these things interconnected form the internet.

Think of IP packets like letters, the letters are put in envelopes, and on the envelopes are the receivers' building address (IP address) and room number (port number) which specify where the letter should be send to, only the receiver has the right to open the envelope and view tge contents, however everyone can see the destination of the letter(so that they can send it forward), you give your letter to your first postman (the router that gives you WIFI), and it's his duty to send it forward to the next postman (node in internet) in line, and through many postmen the letter will reach its destination, now your letter isn't stamped and the first postman sees the room number should only be reachable if the letter is stamped, so he refuses to send it to the next postman, that's it.

Comment: In utorrent app I changed the port used for incoming connections to port 80, 443 and 6875.. and utorrent was unable to download anything. BUT, when I set it to 6885, 48000, 50000...the download started within a few minutes! I think your answer's first Paragraph is completely correct.

Comment: when **not** logged in to the wifi network,doing `ping 8.8.8.8` I got "timed out" messages. Can you explain this please?

Comment: If you can't use the wifi network, you would not be able to reach it as you don't have wifi access then.

Comment: @Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς thanks for the edit! I tested and found out that In addition to those few TCP/UDP ports, the ICMP is also banned (**these are only banned when I am not logged in**).

When I was not logged in to the WiFi... I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 , It simply returned "timed out".

When I was logged in to the Wifi Network.. I tried again. It returned the response.

Comment: @Xeнεi, when **not** logged in to the Wifi network, is it possible to send request  as well as get response from a server via the ports that aren't banned (ports 6885, 48000, 50000, etc)? Will I be able to get a response from my server by typing in the address bar: `http://myServerThatIsSetupSomewhere:48000`? Sorry this seems to me like a stupid question but this question will clear a doubt that is in my mind.

Comment: Nope, you can't do this for normal websites, for example, try to access this address: https://www.google.com:80, you can't because the port number is wrong, however like I said you can't do this for normal websites, some websites, typically proxies, purposefully use uncommon port numbers, and yes you can set the remote port to unbanned ports and browse the internet through the proxy, though it is not without caveats: typically these things aren't free, and free ones aren't of good quality.

Comment: So, I think setting up a nodejs proxy server in heroku or linode can help. That server will listen for tcp connections from "singing sun" on port 50000. using proxy server will serve "singing sun" his requested page through that same tcp connection  on port 50000. Lucky "singing sun" now doesnt need to pay for internet bills.

Comment: What do you say @XeнεiΞэnвϵς? will my suggestion work?